# Get the name of the parent of a nested derived class (C#)

Tags: c#, class, reflection, nested, parent

Example. How get name "Parent" in Nested class.
Nested class can be initialized in any class and to get his name.

```
public class Parent
{
    public ParentNested n = new ParentNested();
}
public class Nested
{
    public Nested()
    {
        // return "Parent" ???
        string ParentName = GetParentClassName();
    }
}
public class ParentNested : Nested { }
```

Comment: but Nested does not have any parent ? Is your code, or question correct?

Comment: Need to get the name of the class in which initialized inner class (variable). I think that this is only possible using a trace. But it would be somehow easier.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the design related issues, you *can* get the info using reflection;

```
    public Nested()
    {
        Type type;
        for (int i = 1;; i++)
        {
            // Get the method in the i'th stack frame
            var method = new StackFrame(i).GetMethod();
            if (method == null) return;

            // Get the class declaring the method
            type = method.DeclaringType;
            if (type == null) return;

            // If the class isn't a parent class, use it.
            if (!type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Nested)))
                break;
        }
        _parent = type.FullName;    // Will be set to "Parent"
    }
```

This simple version will look for the first non base class in the call stack, and save that to _parent.

Comment: Thank you. If modified, it may be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So you want instances of the `Nested` class to figure out who "owns" them?

Since the question is tagged with "reflection", let me just say that you can't do this with reflection.

But if instances of `Nested` logically need to know about the object that owns them, then you need to tell them that. You can pass an instance of the owner (`Parent`) to an instance of `Nested` like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public ParentNested n;

    public Parent()
    {
         n = new ParentNested(this);    
    }
}

public class Nested
{
    public Nested(object owner)
    {
        // return "Parent" ???
        string ParentName = owner.GetType().Name;
    }
}

public class ParentNested : Nested
{
    public ParentNested(object owner) : base(owner) {}
}
```

Comment: This option is used and understood. But do not want to call (this). And you want to restrict that instead of "this" could not use any other type. I wanted to show this as an option in the example used, but did not complicate the code.

Comment: @Clevelus As I said, an object does not know who created it. There's no "trick" to leverage to create the restriction you're looking for. The compiler can only help you so far - from then on, you're on your own.

Comment: Yes. Then just use the trace?

Comment: @Clevelus If by "trace", you mean passing `this` to instances of `Nested`, then yes.

Comment: Also, it seems to me you're jumping through hoops to solve a problem that would be better solved by rethinking the overall design.

Comment: Just turns out that every time you need to call the constructor with the same parameter "this". This class can be used in a variety of others. Moreover, it is not possible to use Nested class with an empty constructor and inheritance it should be implemented.

Comment: About rethinking the design too I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now used like this. But there is a need in many places use a constructor with a parameter "this". Using as a parameter of any class is limited interface. But Nested class inheritance accounts for another designer and write.

```
public interface IParent { }
public class Parent : IParent
{
    public ParentNested n;
    public Parent()
    {
        n = new ParentNested(this);
    }
}
public class Nested
{
    private IParent _parent;
    public Nested(IParent parent)
    {
        // return "Parent"
        _parent = parent;
    }
}
public class ParentNested : Nested
{
    public ParentNested(IParent parent) : base(parent) { }
}
```